# seaborn heatmap conditional border

Tags: seaborn, heatmap

I have a dataframe of gene names, fold changes, and p-values.

I can use `seaborn.heatmap` to plot fold change as a color gradient.

How can I add a conditional border around particular cells whose p-values are < 0.05?

Comment: try to divide and conquer - plot each of the cells separately and if needed - add the border around it

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit unclear how your dataframe looks like and how you create the heatmap.

The code below creates a heatmap from some random data and creates a border (and optionally, hatching) around certain cells:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'gene name': np.repeat(list('abcdefg'), 10),
                   'change ID': np.tile(np.arange(10), 7),
                   'fold change': np.random.rand(70),
                   'p-value': np.random.rand(70) * 0.5})
heatmap_data = pd.pivot_table(df, values='fold change', index=['gene name'], columns='change ID')

ax = sns.heatmap(heatmap_data, square=True)
for index, row in df[df['p-value'] < 0.05].iterrows():
    name_pos = heatmap_data.index.get_loc(row['gene name'])
    id_pos = heatmap_data.columns.get_loc(row['change ID'])
    ax.add_patch(Rectangle((id_pos, name_pos), 1, 1, ec='cyan', fc='none', lw=2, hatch='//'))
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]